# Allow duplicating strings in Array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've the following code in HTML:

```
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="row col-sm-12 pull-right paddingDiv">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="marginBottom pull-right">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs"
                            ng-click="wsdlURLs.push('');">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 marginBottom">
                        <input ng-repeat="param in wsdlURLs"
                               type="text"
                               ng-model="param"
                               class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm trying to do the the following, if I click on the + button, it will add a blank string to wsdlURLs, and it will add a (textBox) under it, and the textBox will be bound to the specific param in wsdlURLs, I got errors!

- The binding isn't working
- Duplicating in array (wsdlURLs)

[image: I need to do like this]

Any one can help me?
Thanks

Comment: can you create a plunker for this?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/stkEZ3RUUhtahCcx7Lvs?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $index

```
<input ng-repeat="param in wsdlURLs"
    type="url"
    ng-model="wsdlURLs[$index]"
    class="form-control">
```

You can also use type="url", so angular will validate if your url is valid!

ngRepeat does not allow duplicated keys, so you must to use "track by"

```
ng-repeat="param in wsdlURLs track by $index"
```

Comment: Good, and what about the duplicated?

Comment: ng-repeat does not allow duplicate keys. So, you just use "track by" like this: ng-repeat="param in wsdlURLs track by $index"